# Tags in scraped content must have the same order as they have in the original HTML file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to build a web scraper. My scraper must find all rows which correspond with chosen tags and save them **in the same order as original HTML** to the new `file.md` file.

Tags are specified in an array:

```
list_of_tags_you_want_to_scrape = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'p', 'li']
```

then this gives me only the content within specified  tag:

```
soup_each_html = BeautifulSoup(particular_page_content, "html.parser")
inner_content = soup_each_html.find("article", "container")
```

let's say that this is the result:

```
<article class="container">
  <h1>this is headline 1</h1>
  <p>this is paragraph</p>
  <h2>this is headline 2</h2>
  <a href="bla.html">this won't be shown bcs 'a' tag is not in the array</a>
</article>
```

then I have method which is responsible for writing a line to the `file.md` file if **a tag from the array exists in the content**

```
with open("file.md", 'a+') as f:
    for tag in list_of_tags_you_want_to_scrape:
        inner_content_tag = inner_content.find_all(tag)

        for x in inner_content_tag:
            f.write(str(x))
            f.write("\n")
```

and it does. But the problem is, that it goes through the array (for each) and it will save all `<h1>` first, all `<h2>` on a second place, etc. And that's because that is the order specified in `list_of_tags_you_want_to_scrape` array.

this would be the result:

```
<article class="container">
  <h1>this is headline 1</h1>
  <h2>this is headline 2</h2>
  <p>this is paragraph</p>
</article>
```

so I would like to have them in the right order like the original HTML has. After the first `<h1>` should be `<p>` element.

That means that I would probably need to do for each loop also with `inner_content` and check if each line from this inner_content is equals to at least one of the tags from the array. If yes then save and then move to another line. I tried to do it and made for each for inner_content to get line by line but it gave me an error and I am not sure if it is correct way how to do it. (First day using BeautifulSoup module)

Any tips or advices how to modify my method to achieve this please? thank you!

Comment: Two things: first, as a general matter - if at all possible, you should paste code, not pictures of it (in this case, your output). Second, you should add to your question your `inner_content` (or at least a representative part) so people can see what you're dealing with.

Comment: @JackFleeting I did. Thanks for noticing me.

Comment: @MapeSVK With your most recent example, shouldn't the order be `[h1, h2, p]`, since that is the structure of the HTML itself?

Comment: @Ajax1234 No, it should not. The original order is h1 -> p -> h2. It is just an example. I need to stick with the right order. This is not a topic about how HTML should be structured. This is a topic about having the right order after scraping.

Comment: @MapeSVK Is the input always in the form of `<article>{something}</article>`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 yes, it is. And I just tried your solution and it works! Thank you for your effort!

Comment: @MapeSVK No problem, glad to help!

Comment: @Ajax1234 could you please very briefly explain how your 'parse' method works? Just how would you read the method.

Comment: @MapeSVK Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain the original order of the `html` input, you can use recursion to loop over the `soup.contents` attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
def parse(content, to_scrape = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'p', 'li']):
   if content.name in to_scrape:
      yield content
   for i in getattr(content, 'contents', []):
      yield from parse(i)
```

---

Example:

```
html = """   
<html>
  <body>
      <h1>My website</h1>
      <p>This is my first site</p>
      <h2>See a listing of my interests below</h2>
      <ul>
         <li>programming</li>
         <li>math</li>
         <li>physics</li>
      </ul>
      <h3>Thanks for visiting!</h3>
  </body>
</html>
"""

result = list(parse(soup(html, 'html.parser')))
```

Output:

```
[<h1>My website</h1>, <p>This is my first site</p>, <h2>See a listing of my interests below</h2>, <li>programming</li>, <li>math</li>, <li>physics</li>, <h3>Thanks for visiting!</h3>]
```

As you can see, the original order of the html is maintained, and can now be written to the file:

```
with open('file.md', 'w') as f:
   f.write('\n'.join(map(str, result)))
```

---

Each `bs4` object contains a `name` and `contents` attribute, among others. The `name` attribute is the tag name itself, while the `contents` attribute stores all the child HTML. `parse` uses a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to first check if the passed `bs4` object has a tag that belongs to the `to_scrape` list and if so, `yield`s that value. Lastly, `parse` iterates over the contents of `content`, and calls itself on each element.

Comment: I just changed line: result = list(parse(soup(html, 'html.parser'))) to result = list(parse(inner_content)) as my content was already after soup. Thanks again!